# redux connect with getServerSideProps in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

im trying to pass the state from mapStateToProps to getServerSideProps() but im getting this error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

*note: i tried using next-redux-wrapper to achive this 'getting the state in getServerSideProps()' but nothing worked as it should. so im trying this approach

is it even possible to do it this way?

index.js:

```
 import { connect } from 'react-redux'
 import store from '../redux/store'
 import Product from '../components/Product'

 const getServerSideProps = async (state) => {
   const { products, loading } = state.productList

   return {props: {products: products, loading: loading}}
 }

 const mapStateToProps = function() {
   const state = store.getState()

   return {props: {state: state}}
 }


 export function Home (products) {
   <Product products={products}>
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(getServerSideProps)
```

Comment: I have never seen this :"export default connect(mapStateToProps)(getServerSideProps)"

Comment: You need to pass a React component to the `connect` call, i.e. `connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)`. I would still recommend you look into [`next-redux-wrapper`](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper) as it's more geared towards Next.js.

Comment: @juliomalves hi. i posted my code with next-redux-wrapper in nextjs github a while back  in the issues section. could you take look at it if possible. thank you. https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/423